# How do I set up and reference mlpack libraries in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mlpack

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and I have to admit my Linux skills are weak and are probably the reason that I'm struggling here.

I've run the following commands successfully:

```
sudo apt-get install libmlpack-dev
sudo apt-get install mlpack-bin
```

What's confusing me is that I have no idea where mlpack has been installed to--I'm expecting to see some library files somewhere, as well as some source code for some examples.

In general, when you install libraries like this on Linux, is there one place where you can expect them to be found?

Thanks for helping out a novice!

Answer (score 1):

I asked a colleague for help and got this figured out.

To summarize:

- libmlpack-dev includes the libraries and header files but no source code examples. You can find a couple small [code samples](http://mlpack.org/docs/mlpack-git/doxygen.php?doc=sample.html) on their website, though.
- The libraries are installed to the default location of /usr/lib/ and the headers to the default location of /usr/include/. The nice thing about this is that these folders are already on your path, so you're all set to #include the mlpack headers.

I wrote a [blog post](http://mccormickml.com/2017/02/01/getting-started-with-mlpack/) to describe all the steps for getting started with mlpack for Linux noobs like me :)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for taking the time to make the writeup.  If you don't mind, I'll link to it when other people (e.g. in the IRC channel) ask questions on how to get things set up.

Comment: @ryan - Absolutely, thanks. Any chance you could help me with [another mlpack question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097957/mlpack-nearest-neighbor-with-cosine-distance) I have? Thanks!