# mlpack nearest neighbor with cosine distance?

Tags: c++, metrics, knn, mlpack

I'd like to use the NeighborSearch class in mlpack to perform KNN classification on some vectors representing documents.

I'd like to use Cosine Distance, but I'm having trouble. I think the way to do this is to use the inner-product metric "IPMetric" and specify the CosineDistance kernel... This is what I have:

```
NeighborSearch<NearestNeighborSort, IPMetric<CosineDistance>> nn(X_train);
```

But I get the following compile errors:

```
/usr/include/mlpack/core/tree/hrectbound_impl.hpp:211:15: error: ‘Power’ is not a member of ‘mlpack::metric::IPMetric<mlpack::kernel::CosineDistance>’
 sum += pow((lower + fabs(lower)) + (higher + fabs(higher)),
           ^
/usr/include/mlpack/core/tree/hrectbound_impl.hpp:220:3: error: ‘TakeRoot’ is not a member of ‘mlpack::metric::IPMetric<mlpack::kernel::CosineDistance>’
if (MetricType::TakeRoot)
^
```

I suspect that the problem may be that the default tree type, KDTree, does not support this distance metric? If that's the issue, is there a tree type that does work for CosineDistance?

Finally, is it possible to use a brute-force search? I can't seem to find a way to use no tree at all...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, like you suspected, arbitrary metric types don't work with the KDTree---this is because the kd-tree requires a distance that can be decomposed into different dimensions.  But that is not possible with `IPMetric`.  Instead, why not try using the cover tree?  The build time of the tree may be somewhat longer but it should give comparable performance:

```
NeighborSearch<NearestNeighborSort, IPMetric<CosineDistance>, arma::mat,
    tree::StandardCoverTree> nn(X_train);
```

If you want to do brute-force search, specify the search mode in the constructor:

```
NeighborSearch<NearestNeighborSort, IPMetric<CosineDistance>, arma::mat,
    tree::StandardCoverTree> nn(X_train, NAIVE_MODE);
```

I hope this is helpful; let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Ack, I should add two things: I think `tree::BallTree` will also work for you here, and also, is your task finding the points with maximum cosine similarity?  The setup you're using will find the points with minimum cosine similarity.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried using BallTree, but I'm still getting compile errors... It's saying that neighbor search requires binary_space_tree, which uses hrectbound, which requires the LMetric. I've shared my code [here](https://github.com/chrisjmccormick/mlpack-examples/blob/master/reuters_example_cosine.cpp#L52) and the compiler output [here](https://github.com/chrisjmccormick/mlpack-examples/blob/master/error_output.txt) if that helps. Could be that I'm doing something stupid with the #includes?

Comment: I see you're using mlpack 2.0.2, so use `true` as the second parameter to the constructor instead of `NAIVE_MODE`.  Something is not adding up with the code and compiler output you gave; it shouldn't be instantiating the HRectBound class at all if BallTree is being used.  Are you sure this is a clean build?

Comment: I think I may have figured it out -- NeighborSearch also takes a 'TraversalType' as a template parameter, and the default is mlpack::tree::BinarySpaceTree, which is generating those compile errors.  Any insight to what I should set TraversalType to?

Comment: That's strange, the TraversalType should default to the given TreeType, not to BinarySpaceTree.  You can probably set it to `BallTree<IPMetric<CosineDistance>, NeighborSearchStat<NearestNeighborSort>>, arma::mat>::DualTreeTraverser` and I think that will work.  Would you like to open a bug on the mlpack github, though?  I think that you have uncovered a problem.